# Vibration when lightly hitting one of the walls in an apartment?

Tags: repair, walls, structural, vibration

I bought an apartment and I'm in the process of renovating it.

One weird thing I noticed in one of the rooms is that when I hit the wall with my fist lightly, the entire wall and maybe even the room vibrates and resonates for a good second or so afterwards. This doesn't happen anywhere else.

On the other side of the wall, there is a closet. There is another room on the other side of the closet, hitting the wall there doesn't cause vibration. This is a brick and concrete apartment building in Europe, Floor 7 of 9. The building is 50 years old. The wall is made of bricks.

Anyone have any ideas or explanation on why that might be happening?

Comment: What’s on the other side of the wall? With the very little information you’ve given it sounds like somebody decided to add a wall at some point.  What is the wall made of?  Is the construction of that wall different in appearance in any way from others?  How old is the apt building? Where on the planet is it located?

Comment: All good questions by @Tyson. I would add, is this in a basement, ground floor, mid floor, or top floor?